# Store is not found+Data Migrating From M1.8.1.0 To M2.2.4

Tags: magento2.2, data-migration, data-migration-tool

**Step 1:-** php bin/magento migrate:settings --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/config.xml

It's working fine for me.

**Step2:-**  php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/config.xml

**Getting " [Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException] Requested store is not found" error.**

**Note:-**

1- Magento1 site has 2 stores, English & French.

2- Before starting Migration I've already added some categories, both of stores (English,French),CMS pages,static blocks etc manually On Magento2 site.

3- By data migration :-

I only needed product with attributes,orders, customer data so is this possible?

So please help me to either resolve issue OR any alternative of Note3.